# One way relay (manual reset )?

Tags: relay, power-electronics, solid-state-relay

What I mean by one way relay is manually reset it to run again.
What I need it for:

I want a pump to run when a relay is on(manually turned on), when there is no power the relay trips and stays like that in off position. Because even if the power comes back on I don't want the pump on. Until I reset the relay.

I keep saying a relay, but it doesn't have to be. Anything that could handle 240V.
Is there anything I could use for this?

Comment: It is called a latching relay and can be made from any relay with two sets of contacts. try google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common requirement for machine controls. You can buy switches with this function built-in - Look on Amazon for "motor safety switch".

A typical DIY circuit is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy8M3v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Beat me to it...

Comment: An NVR switch should do it then.